# WooCommerce validate billing_address_1 checkout field

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to validate one of our WooCommerce checkout fields, namely billing_address_1.

Right now, the field will accept any address but it should check to see if the address field contains a number before processing. Not sure how this should be done in WooCommerce. I will also accept any other solution which are non WooCommerce.

The website is: https://www.prikkabelled.nl

You should be looking at this field at checkout:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validation for this. Change below code as per your requirement:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'is_phone');

function is_phone() { 
    $addr1 = $_POST['billing_address_1'];
    // check condition if number not found in address
    if(false)
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Address does not contain a number.' ), 'error' );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step you can add to the checkout progress via functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'custom_checkout_field_check');

function custom_checkout_field_check() {
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ( $_POST['billing_address_1'] && strpbrk($_POST['billing_address_1'], '1234567890') !== FALSE )
        wc_add_notice( __( 'Your address field contains numeric value' ), 'error' );
}
```

Comment: I didn't do anything special, simply pasted what you provided in functions.php

Comment: This should work unless you changed something to the code. Try to check it with the core Woocommerce template files.

Comment: When I do a var_dump of these four variable, they all return bool(false).

var_dump($_POST['billing_address_1'] == true);
var_dump($_POST['billing_address_2'] == true);
var_dump($_POST['billing_postcode'] == true);
var_dump($_POST['billing_email'] == true);

Did these fields get different names somehow? How can I trace what they are now?

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer I was looking for which I got straight from the WooCommerce developer community.

```
// Check if address field contains house number otherwise provide error message

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_validation', 'validate_checkout', 10, 2); 

function validate_checkout( $data, $errors ){ 
    if (  ! preg_match('/[0-9]/', $data[ 'billing_address_1' ] ) ){ 
        $errors->add( 'address', 'Sorry, but the address you provided does not contain a house number.' ); 
    }
}
```